# Is it possible for Pandoc to take text as an input argument rather than an input file?

Tags: pandoc

I can't seem to figure out if this is possible. Still trying to learn the tool - I've figured out how to  run it on an input file and generate outputs, but would it be possible for it to, for example, take a text as an input and generate an output file.

For e.g., instead of

`pandoc -i somefile.md -o -f markdown -t docx output.md`

could I do

`pandoc "# hello there! \n\nI went to the market" -o -f markdown -t docx output.md`

Am I missing some option in the doc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass text input to pandoc. I did so by using the pipe operator:

```sh
echo "# hello there! \n\nI went to the market" | pandoc -f markdown -t docx -o foo.docx
```

This works with other text markups:

```sh
echo "* hello there! \n\nI went to the market" | pandoc -f org -t docx -o foo.docx
```

If you are targeting another text-based markup, you can even get it to print out text:

```sh
echo "# hello there! \n\nI went to the market" | pandoc -f markdown -t org
* hello there!
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: hello-there
  :END:

I went to the market
```

Comment: Are you aware of a way to pass it as an argument rather than echo it through a pipe?

Comment: I'm marking this as answered as I was able to make this work. Would've preferred an input method but since I'm executing a shell anyway, this works too!

Comment: @Gerry I am not aware of a means of passing it through as an argument

Comment: No worries, this works for now, thank you!

Comment: On Linux (with `zsh` shell), this doesn't work for the `latex` input format: `echo "\documentclass{article}\begin{document}foobar\end{document}" | pandoc -f latex -t org` gives an empty output.